# Editing a page definition file during runtime in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

Can we  create or edit a page definition file during runtime in ADF?
If yes, Can anyone please provide the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your JDeveloper version. After `"Hot Swap"` of Java classes, Oracle now proposed `"Hot Deployment"` of ADF Projects" beginning from 12c.

You can find detailed information in the following link: https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/hotdeployment_in_jdeveloper_12c_don

Comment: Thanks for the response Gokhan :)